# Merging tables of different sizes by column Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables like this:

```
Table A:

id id2 value
1   1   a
1   2   b
2   1   c
3   1   d

Table B:

id value2
1    e
2    g
3    h
```

And I need to join them so i get something like this:

```
Table needed:

id   id2  value value2
1     1     a     e
1     2     b     e
2     1     c     g
3     1     d     h
```

Excel or Python or R would work. The fact is i need that if the id in table A matches with the one in table B, the value in table b gets added to the matchin row(s). Nevertheless, both tables are not of the same size and some times there are id's in table b that do not exist in table a. I only need the ones in table a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest is use `map`:

```
df1['value2'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['value2'])
print (df1)
   id  id2 value value2
0   1    1     a      e
1   1    2     b      e
2   2    1     c      g
3   3    1     d      h
```

EDIT:

```
print (df2)
   id value2
0   1      e
1   1      p
2   2      g
3   3      h

df1['value2'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['value2'])
print (df1)
```

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Ans solution is remove them:

```
print (df2)
   id value2
0   1      e
1   1      p
2   2      g
3   3      h

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset='id')
print (df2)
   id value2
0   1      e
2   2      g
3   3      h

df1['value2'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['value2'])
print (df1)
   id  id2 value value2
0   1    1     a      e
1   1    2     b      e
2   2    1     c      g
3   3    1     d      h
```

Solution with repeating values with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left')
print (df)
   id  id2 value value2
0   1    1     a      e
1   1    1     a      p
2   1    2     b      e
3   1    2     b      p
4   2    1     c      g
5   3    1     d      h
```

Comment: I get the following error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: It means in table 2 are duplicates.

Comment: Yes, there are indexes that are repeated, and what I need is for the value to repeat itself in that case.

Comment: Super, also I add solution if need repeating duplicates values.